# Javascript breaks other script

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, blogger

Whenever I add the code below as a widget to my blog, the slider (Welcome...) on it will stop working. The slider should scroll through a few different images. I've read that 'no.conflict' will fix this problem but for the life of me haven't a clue where to put the code.

Recent Videos Widget

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<style type="text/css">
div.PBTytC {clear:both;padding:5px;font-size:12px;}
div.PBTytC.odd {background-color: #;}
div.PBTytC_thumb {position:relative;float:left;margin-right:8px;line-height:1;}
div.PBTytC_thumb img {width:76px;height:78px;border:0px solid #55A66B;}
div.PBTytC_title {font-weight:none;}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var PBTYoutubeUserName = "XXX";
var PBTYoutubeMAXResults = 3;
var PBTYoutubeAllow = "";
var PBTYoutubeDisallow = "";
var PBTYoutubeWgetIsEmpty = "No entries";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=58c841d14337ba4fbf693abd9701dc49&_render=json&max-results="+PBTYoutubeMAXResults+"&allow="+PBTYoutubeAllow+"&disallow="+PBTYoutubeDisallow+"&user="+PBTYoutubeUserName+"&_callback=?", function(response) {
    var htm = "";
    for(var i=0;i<response.count;i++) {
      var item = response.value.items[i];
      htm += '<div class="PBTytC';
      if(i%2 == 1) htm += ' odd';
      htm += '"><div class="PBTytC_thumb"><a target="_blank" href="' + item.link + '"><img title="' + item.title + '" src="' + item.thumb + '"/></a></div>';
      htm += '<div class="PBTytC_title"><a target="_blank" href="' + item.link + '">' + item.title + '</a></div>';
      htm += '<div class="PBTytC_description">' + item.description + '</div><div style="clear:both;"></div></div>';
    }
    if(htm == "") htm = PBTYoutubeWgetIsEmpty;
    $("#PBTytWdtLoad").html(htm);
  });
});
</script>
<div id="PBTytWdtLoad">Loading...</div>
```

Here is the link to my blog: [Link](http://scruffy-studio.blogspot.com)

Thanks for reading and hopefully helping me out.

Comment: Open console and check for errors

Comment: And the error you are seeing are? or should we guess?

Comment: Look at all those pretty global variables. What is the thing that breaks because of this code? Are both using a global `$` in _JavaScript_ to mean different things?

Comment: Console doesn't show any errors. The code is what I found from a website somewhere, its the first line that breaks the slider: <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including JQuery twice can cause issues. The code fragment above and your blog both have a script tag for query. Try adding it to your blog without including JQuery again.

As for the plugin not working:

Your site includes JQuery; Then it has a lot of scripts that use JQuery; Then it has a script that changes the JQuery operator so that `$` isn't use since this will cause conflicts with other scripts using the variable `$` in another way. Considering the amount of scripts on your site I'm surprised you don't have more issues.

Anyway after your last script tag you can't use `$` in your scripts you have to use `jQuery` instead. For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.getJSON("http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?
```

If you go through your whole script and change '$' to 'jQuery' then that will help with your script where it is in your page now, with the current page listed at your blog.

Really though, this is just putting a band-aid on a bigger problem. It's worth thinking about what scripts you really need.

Comment: Yes, I'm not very good with Jquery but can't figure out where to put no.conflict in the widget code.

Comment: Question: How do I get this to not stop working. Possible Answer: Don't include JQuery twice. **It is an answer.** And, I can't comment yet. I didn't design the flawed system, I'm simply working within it.

Comment: Then how do I tell the widget to load the JQuery that is already being used by the slider?

Comment: You don't need to tell it to. If the browser has loaded it (and it's in the head of your html so it has) then you don't need to reload it. Is that actually your problem though? I was just guessing and would have just made a comment if I could have.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yeah that's my problem. I've removed the line that loads the jguery (so it doesn't load it the second time as you said) but still the widget is not working. Keeps saying loading... Do I need to change the $ global variables in the widget?

Comment: I've updated my answer above. It's because you include a script to make jQuery not use the variable `$` anymore. This can will stop conflicts with other scripts that use `$` for other purposes. If none of your scripts use `$` then you don't need the this script. If there are, then you need to use the variable `jQuery` instead. I've put an example above.